# Gauge invariance / charge conservation on string ending on brane

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, branes

Consider a fundamental string charged under the Kalb-Ramond 2-form $B$ and ending on a D5-brane. Charge conservation implies the existence of a 1-form gauge field $A$ with field strength $F$ living on the D5-brane. The 10-d action is then (ignoring kinetic terms for the field strength $H=dB$) $$\tag{1}\int_\text{spacetime}T\ B\wedge\delta^{8}-B\wedge\delta^4\wedge\star_6F$$ where the $\delta$-functions localise the terms on the string worldsheet and on the D5 worldvolume, respectively. $T$ is the charge density / tension. Note that the Hodge dual is only on the 6d worldvolume of D5.

I guess the action is postulate to be this because then you can obtain from it the usual Maxwell equation $d\star F=j_e$ i.e. the string endpoint acts as a point-like electric source on the D5 worldvolume, which is what we want.

I've also seen the following argument. Consider only a term $$\tag{2}T\int_\text{spacetime} B\wedge\delta^8=T\int_\text{string worldsheet}B$$ where I omitted pullback notation of $B$ to the worldsheet. Under a gauge transformation $\delta B=d\Lambda$, we have a boundary term $$T\int_\text{string worldsheet boundary}\Lambda$$
so that for gauge invariance of the action, we have to introduce a gauge field $A$ (I am suggestively using the same notation as above, as I expect the two fields denoted $A$ are in fact the same field) which transforms as $\delta A=\Lambda$. We add a boundary term to the action $$-T\int_\text{string worldsheet boundary}A.\tag{3}$$
The action is now gauge invariant. The field $A$ can live on the D5 brane. I assume the term in eq (3) is just the second term in eq. (1). I believe this is the case because the way I see it is that the two derivations are equivalent: in one case we use charge conservation to postulate the action (1), while in the second case we start only with the coupling term (2) and then find that gauge invariance requires us to add term (3) to the action. Gauge invariance and charge conservation are fundamentally the same thing, and both fields labelled $A$ are gauge fields on the D5 brane, (and, not going to lie, the fact they both have a negative sign sold me) so I'm convinced that these two routes are totally equivalent. However, ideally I would like to see this equivalence spelt out mathemtically too, so my problem is:

**Q: how can I show that the term (3) is the same as the second term in (1)?**

I have tried pushing forward (3) from the string worldsheet boundary to spacetime, $$-T\int_\text{string worldsheet boundary}A=-T\int_\text{spacetime}\delta^1\wedge A$$ and I'm not sure how to proceed -- I can't see why the 6d Hodge dual would appear, why $B$ itself would appear, and where does the tension $T$ go. Any help would be much appreciated thanks.